# How do I create a server that serves API and falls back to disk using Iron?

Tags: rust, iron

I tried the following:

```
let mut router = Router:new();
router.get("/hello",  |_: &mut Request| {
  Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, "hello")))
}, "/hello");

let mut mount = Mount::new();
mount.mount("/", router)
     .mount("/", Static::new(Path::new("src/public/")));
```

But it results in "no such file or directory" errors when I try to access `/hello`:

```
Request {
    url: Url { generic_url: "http://localhost:10800/hello" }
    method: Get
    remote_addr: V4(127.0.0.1:57260)
    local_addr: V4(127.0.0.1:10800)
}
Error was: Error { repr: Os { code: 2, message: "No such file or directory" } }
```

Comment: From [`Mount`'s documentation](https://docs.rs/mount/0.3.0/mount/struct.Mount.html#method.mount): *Existing handlers on the same route will be overwritten.*

Comment: @Shepmaster - Yes, that's true. Maybe there is a way to achieve this without Mount?

Comment: *`let mut router = Router:new();`* this isn't valid Rust code for the stable version of Rust (1.18.0). I don't know how you could have lost a `:` in the middle of the code that you copied from your [MCVE]. Please go ahead and paste the *entire* MCVE to make it easier for other people to answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a `Router` at all; just pass the handler directly to `mount`:

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate mount;
extern crate staticfile;

use iron::prelude::*;
use iron::status;
use mount::Mount;
use staticfile::Static;

use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let hello = |_: &mut Request| {
        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, "hello")))
    };

    let mut mount = Mount::new();
    mount.mount("/hello", hello)
        .mount("/", Static::new(Path::new("src/public/")));

    let _server = Iron::new(mount).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();
    println!("On 3000");
}
```

```
$ curl localhost:3000/animal
cow
$ curl localhost:3000/hello
hello
```